# Datagrid search values from database in WPF

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf, datagrid

I'm currently developing a Search TextBox with Datagrid to view data from database in a C# & WPF application. But I need to use some inner joins in my query. The problem is when I input some text (name) in texbox i receive a messabox: Incorrect sintaxe near cad. I execute this query in sql server and it works fine, but in c# doesn't. 
This is my code:

```
private void txt_SearchCad(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            _con = new SqlConnection(_strConn);

            try
            {
                _con.Open();
                string query = "select cad.id AS ID, cad.name AS Name, cad.date AS Date, cad.age AS Age,"+
                                "agegroup.name AS AgeGroup,activity.name AS Activity, professional.name AS Professional"+ 
                                "from cad inner join agegroup on cad.fokagegroup = agegroup.id"+
                                "inner join activity on cad.fokativity = activity.id"+
                                "inner join professional on cad.fokprofissional = profissional.id";
                if (txtSearchName.Text != "")
                {
                    query += " where cad.name like '%" + txtSearchName.Text + "%'";
                }
                _cmd = new SqlCommand(query, _con);
                _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                _adp = new SqlDataAdapter(_cmd);
                _dt = new DataTable("cad");
                _adp.Fill(_dt);
                dgList.ItemsSource = _dt.DefaultView;
                _adp.Update(_dt);

                _con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: At least, in the above query there are some spaces missing that could case syntax errors (e.g.: `"professional.name AS Professional"+"from cad inner"`). The `+` operator just appends one string to another and it doesn't add any space between your strings.

Comment: put a break point and check the exact error you are getting

Comment: @AlbertoSolano, Thanks Works fine!. I didn't pay attention. Just put spaces.

Comment: @coreid You're welcome. Such problems are so frequent and always a bummer. :)